# Sample Navigation Folding Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, folding

I want to share a demo on Navigation Folding Drawer. How do I do it?

I've come across some really pernicious problems where there is either no good information available or the good information is buried under a sea of bad information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the Folding Layout library.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.ptr.folding.FoldingDrawerLayout;

public class DemoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private FoldingDrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mAnimalTitles;

    private ItemSelectedListener mItemSelectedListener;

    static final boolean IS_HONEYCOMB = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mAnimalTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (FoldingDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // mFoldLayout = (FoldingNavigationLayout)findViewById(R.id.fold_view);
        // mFoldLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mAnimalTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mItemSelectedListener = new ItemSelectedListener();

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                if (IS_HONEYCOMB) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                    // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

            }

            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                if (IS_HONEYCOMB) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                    // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }


    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new AnimalFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(AnimalFragment.ARG_ANIMAL_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mAnimalTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    }

    /**
     * Listens for selection events of the spinner located on the action bar.
     * Every time a new value is selected, the number of folds in the folding
     * view is updated and is also restored to a default unfolded state.
     */
    private class ItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int mNumberOfFolds = Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());

            mDrawerLayout.getFoldingLayout(mDrawerList).setNumberOfFolds(mNumberOfFolds);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screen-shot:

[image]